# Elasticsearch case insensitive nested query string

Tags: elasticsearch

I haven't defined any analyzers and assume it's using the standard analyzer

ES version : 5.6
Lucene_version : 6.6.1

Normal query string results in case-insensitive search but if the query string is put inside nested query it results in case sensitive search

Non-nested query string

```
GET articles/_search
{
   query : {
      bool : {
         must : [ {
            query_string : { 
                query : "*ellow*
            }}]} 
}
```

Nested query string doesn't return case insensitive matches

```
GET articles/_search {    query : {
      bool : {
         must : [ {
           nested : {
              path : "comments", 
              query : {
                query_string : { 
                   query : "*ellow*"
            }}}} ]} }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you add your mappings for reference?

Comment: working fine for me as i am not able to reproduce this